# How to create dataframe based on matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, nlp

There are two dataframe I have "df1" and "df2" and one matrix "res"

```
df1=    a       df2 =   a
        b               c   
        c               e
        d
```

there are 4 record in df1 and 3 record in df2
so,
res = 4*3 matrix

```
res =
                   df2(index)
                   0    1   2
             0     100  0   0
df1(index)   1     0    0   0
             2     0    100 0
             3     0    0   0
```

so I have above data based on this data or matrix I want following output in the form of dataframe

```
   df1  df2 score
    a   a   100
    a   c   0
    a   e   0
    b   a   0
    b   c   0
    b   e   0
    c   a   0
    c   c   100
    c   e   0
    d   a   0
    d   c   0
    d   e   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set index and columns names by `df1, df2`:

```
res.index = df1[:len(res.index)]
res.columns = df2[:len(res.columns)]
```

And then reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = res.rename_axis(index='df1', columns='df2').melt(ignore_index=False)
```

Or [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = res.rename_axis(index='df1', columns='df2').stack().reset_index(name='value')
```

Comment: Length mismatch error

Comment: @ShubhamKorade - so it means legth of columns, index of `res` is different like length of `df1, df2`.

Comment: @jezrael- exactly

Comment: @ShubhamKorade - answer was edited, can you check?